# Magento 2.3 EE Bulk Asynchronous API Operations using RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.3, rabbit-mq

We are currently testing the Bulk Asynchronous API Operations in **Magento 2.3 EE** (clean installation) with **RabbitMQ**.  The issue we are finding is whilst creating configurable and simple products.  It appears something is being cached preventing the different payloads from being successfully received by Magento.

The payloads in question are:

1. **rest/async/bulk/V1/products** (used to create the simple and configurable products)
2. **rest/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/options** (used to create the configurable product options)
3. **rest/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/child** (used to link the child SKU to the parent)

The issues we are seeing are as follows:

If a payload hasn't been received for a few minutes the 1st item in the array never gets processed. The bulk status endpoint (**rest/V1/bulk/:bulkuuid/detailed-status**) shows a status of 4 (pending).  Submitting the payload again processes the missed item.

Creating the configurable options (**rest/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/options**) returns "*An error occurred while saving the option. Please try to save again*".

The only way we can get this to work is if we force a close on the connection in **RabbitMQ** (via the Management Plugin) in between each payload.  Everything then completes successfully. e.g.

1. Close the connection in **RabbitMQ** (wait for the connection to come alive again)
2. Send the create products payload (**rest/async/bulk/V1/products**) - All items processed successfully
3. Close the connection in RabbitMQ (wait for the connection to come alive again)
4. Send the create configurable product options payload (**rest/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/options**)
5. Close the connection in RabbitMQ (wait for the connection to come alive again)
6. Send the link child to parent payload (**rest/async/bulk/V1/configurable-products/bySku/child**)

We are struggling to understand whether this is a configuration issue in RabbitMQ, Magento or a bug with the bulk API framework.

As mentioned this is a clean installation of Magento 2.3 EE

> RabbitMQ version = 3.7.9
>
> Erlang version = 21.2.4

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm currently investigating this issue.

I'm creating and deleting products with rabbitmq. The issue appears while saving product after deleting another one (or the same one). The actual exception message is: 

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`catalog_product_super_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`

It occurs because there are valid values already inside the above table, but that code is firing only once.